# Table body width relative to table head

Tags: java, html, css

I am using Trinidad JSF framework and trying to build a fixed header and scrolling tbody table. I could achieve this, but the tbody columns were not as width of thead, when there is no data for most of the columns in table body. Please see below.
[image]

Code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
<style>
.af_table_content {

 border-spacing: 1;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.af_table_content tbody, .af_table_content thead {
 display: block; 
}
.af_table_content tbody tr {
table-layout:fixed;
}
.af_table_content thead tr th {
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 /* text-align: left; */
}

.af_table_content tbody {
 height: 100px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 border-top: 1px solid black;  
}

.af_table_content tbody td,.af_table_content thead th { 
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

.af_table_content tbody td:last-child,.af_table_content thead th:last-child
 {
 border-right: none;
}
</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<table class="af_table_content" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0"
 border="0" width="100%">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 1</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 2</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 3</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 4</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 5</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 6</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 7</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 8</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 9</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 10</span></th>
  <th scope="col" ><span
   >Column 11</span></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td >    
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><span
   >value</span></td>
  <td ><span
   >1</span></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 

 </tbody>
 </table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Have you tried applying `<table style="table-layout:fixed">`?

Comment: yes just now. it extends the table to the whole page width and remains the same.

Comment: With your html and your css I can't duplicate the issue, not even if I put them together in one snippet.

Comment: @MrLister I have edited the code snippet in my original question. To replciate the issue, please open in chrome.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now, but that trick requires some extra javascript to restore the cell widths.

Comment: @MrLister i should have said you this, i use trinidad jsf framework and their component tag tr:table generates table with all header and data under tag <tbody> instead of header in <thead> and content in <tbody>. So i wrote this query in run time to aligning them in runtime. `var $table = $("table.af_table_content");
$table.find('tbody tr:first').wrap('<thead/>').parent()  .prependTo($table);` Does this made any issues in alignment? Also this table scroll is not working in IE, not sure what is going wrong in IE.